# what does this command do sed 's/~/ /g'?

Tags: linux, sed

I am passing a set of 6 arguments initially to a script.

```
Script.sh a b c d e f
```

One of the commands in the script which is managing the arguments;

```
comm=$(echo $1 |sed 's/~/ /g')
```

Comment: Imho, some at least basic research should be done before asking questions. You can find the answer in the info text of `sed` tag which has been used in this question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/sed/info

Answer (score 14):

The `sed` expression `s/~/ /g` replaces every tilde with a space character.  It means, literally, "substitute everything that matches the regular expression `~` with a space, globally (on the whole input line)".  The expression could in this case also have been written as the quicker `y/~/ /`, and the whole `sed` command could be replaced by the even faster `tr '~' ' '`.

In `bash`, this is more efficiently done with

```
comm=${1//\~/ }
```

The `~` has to be escaped or quoted here to not be expanded to the pathname of the current user's home directory.

In any case, the `$1` needs to be double quoted if you are using it with `echo` (unless you want shell globs to be expanded to filenames), and ideally, the command would be written with `printf` (this avoids an initial dash in `$1` from being interpreted as the start of some option to `echo`, and avoids having certain backslash sequences interpreted under some circumstances):

```
comm=$( printf '%s\n' "$1" | tr '~' ' ' )
```

Related:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)

Comment: Re: "globally (on the whole input line)": where can I find it in `man sed`? I see only "g G - Copy/append hold space to pattern space." Is this what I'm looking for?

Comment: @pmor The `g` here is a "flag" for the `s` command, so you should be looking at the documentation for the `s` command.  The `g` and `G` commands are not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! Now I [see](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html): "g Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first."